# google maps v3 appears distorted and doubled

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

This code works perfectly on jsfiddle and any other JavaScript sandbox app, but it doesn't work on my website.

**HTML :**

```
<div id="mapcontainer" style="position:absolute;width:280px;height:160px;"></div>
```

**JS :**

```
<script src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=*********************************&sensor=false"></script>
<script>
    var myCenter = new google.maps.LatLng(33.436150, -117.623090);

    function initialize() {
        var mapProp = {
            center: myCenter,
            zoom: 9,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };

        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("mapcontainer"), mapProp);

        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: myCenter,
        });

        marker.setMap(map);

        google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize')
    }

    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
</script>
```

It looks like this:

[image]

Notice how the top 2/3 is distorted and the bottom 1/3 is fine. How can I fix this?

Comment: Do you have a link to your website then as it must be being caused by something else? Probably conflicting JS or CSS.

Comment: my website is at oceankarma.co...the username is oceankarma and the password is Tycoonaks90

Comment: just wondering...what did you edit?

Comment: I edited the formatting, spelling, grammar and wording. Try disabling/commenting out all of the other JS you have running on the page. So only the Google Maps code is loaded and run.

Comment: For diagnosis, initialize the map in response to a button click instead of `google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);`.

Comment: I commented out all the other code, and it makes no difference.

Comment: Do you have a live link or a jsfiddle that shows the problem?

Answer (score 1):

> It seems there must be some other problem in code.

Your google maps code looks perfect, I have made a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/praveen_jegan/9urKM/1/) to show the difference.

From your script it seems you're **using key for google maps**.  I think that is not necessary in v3.  so try replacing it as shown below.

```
<script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
```

Comment: I copied and pasted the code from your fiddle and it makes no difference.

Comment: @DABAU5NERD I checked your site and it seems to be fine?  Can you share your thoughts on that fix?

Comment: oh I used an iframe and linked it to a blank html page with only the map element and scripts

Answer (score 1):

I stumbled over this page after I had the same problem myself on a google map I was developing. The solution I came up with was to add the following code after the google map javascript.

```
$(window).resize(function(){ initMap(); });
```

The "initMap();" part is so it just refreshes the map function. If you named the function something different that is what you need to use.
Ultimately I realize this is a patch to the problem. But it works like a charm and is barely noticeable to the end user. All you are doing is refreshing the map function when you resize the window.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out a similar issue due to the solution to this problem in comments.

It was a case of looking at one of the images in the map with a css debugger and seeing if it was affected by any other styles on the page